# How to configure https for my REST application?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, https, restful-architecture

*Consider **next***:

1. I have a restful api, created with java and deployed on tomcat server.
2. I have a client application, based on angularjs and deployed on npm http-server.
3. I have a jwt authentication flow and need to add https security.

I'm a bit new to such rest details, so there is a ***question***

- Should be https configured only for my api on tomcat, or I need an additional configuration also for http-server?

browser -> *http* -> angularjs client -> *https* -> rest api

or

browser -> *https* -> angularjs client -> *https* -> rest api

or *?*

Comment: I'm no expert on angularjs but if the browser and the angularjs client communicate via http then this probably is the most important interface to secure, i.e. having https here is a must. You want to prevent any access to the data that is exchanged between the user's browser/app and your servers. Having just inter-server communication secured is somewhat like not locking the doors of your house but just some boxes you store inside and think they can never be stolen because they are locked.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot call a https, from a http site.

Comment: @Thomas - so, I should configure https for both endpoints, right? And will it be ok, if I use the same key and certificate for both configurations?

Comment: browser -> https -> angularjs client -> https -> rest api, because you can't call https from http. Also I hope you've also configured SSL Certificate.

Comment: @PratikAmbani - yes ssl is ok, thx for answer

Comment: @PratikAmbani - do you know will it be ok, if I use the same key and certificate for both https configurations?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you have to go with SSL enabled at both sides as you can not call https from http.

So considering your question, 
Go with **browser -> https -> angularjs client -> https -> rest api**

In this case you'll need to configure SSL Certificate at both ends.

Make sure certificate provided by your Certificate Authority supports multiple installations.